# Node.js req.query.searchQuery is undefined on one occasion and a string with value undefined on another, which screws with my if logic

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am super confused with what is going on right now and I'll try to explain my problem as clearly as I can, considering I don't quite understand what's going on myself.

I have a a Node.js endpoint which returns all products by default, but if some query parameters are present, the MySQL query changes. I'm trying to change the MySQL query based on the presence of some query parameters using if statement, but the problem is that `typeof` the queries is sometimes `undefined` OR a `string` spelling out undefined, which screws with my if statements. Any idea why this could be happening?

```
module.exports.getProducts = async (req, res, next) => {
    let searchQuery = req.query.searchQuery
    let categoryId = req.query.categoryId
    let model = req.query.model

    let query = {
        where: [],
        include: []
    }

    try {
        if (searchQuery !== undefined) {
            query.where.push({
                [Op.or]: [
                    { name: {
                        [Op.substring]: searchQuery
                    }},
                    { serialNumber: {
                        [Op.substring]: searchQuery
                    }}
                ]
            })
        }
        if (categoryId !== undefined) {
            query.where.push({
                categoryId: categoryId
            })
        }
        if (model !== undefined) {
            query.include.push({
                model: Model,
                where: {
                    name: model
                }
            })
        }

        let products = await Product.findAndCountAll(query)

        res.status(200).json({
            products: products.rows
        })
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
        res.status(500)
    }
}
```

Comment: ```
query.include.push({
                model: Model,
                where: {
                    name: model
                }
            })```
You have a typo in `Model`, it should be `model`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I convert string with value undefined to actual undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66877936/can-i-convert-string-with-value-undefined-to-actual-undefined)