# Can I convert string with value 'undefined' to actual undefined?

Tags: javascript

When I make a GET request from my front-end, I apply a couple of query parameters to the url like this:

```
let response = await axios.get('/products?searchQuery=' + this.searchQuery + '&categoryId=' + this.categoryId + '&model=' + this.model + '&page=' + this.currentPage)
```

The problem is that when I `console.log(typeof searchQuery)` on the back-end, it says the searchQuery is a `string` type with value undefined, instead of being `undefined` type. Because of that, this if statement fails:

```
if (searchQuery !== undefined) {

}
```

So I am wondering if it's possible to convert string with value "undefined" to the actual undefined data type.

Comment: It is possible, but why don't you just check for the string variant? I mean, `searchQuery !== 'undefined'`?

Comment: @FZs Because if I make the GET request without query parameters like this let response = await axios.get('/products?page=' + this.currentPage), searchQuery would be undefined type on the back-end.

Comment: [Please don’t do that.](https://www.wired.com/2015/11/null/) Fix whatever is inadvertently converting the actual undefined value to a string in the first place instead of working around it after the fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don’t do this. Seriously. **Don’t. Do. This.** Have you learned nothing from the case of [Mr. Null](https://www.wired.com/2015/11/null/)?

If a parameter is undefined on the front-end, omit it from the request entirely.

```
const usp = new URLSearchParams;
const setIfSet = (usp, key, value) => {
    if (value == void 0) return;
    usp.set(key, value);
};
setIfSet(usp, 'searchQuery', this.searchQuery);
setIfSet(usp, 'categoryId', this.categoryId);
setIfSet(usp, 'model', this.model);
setIfSet(usp, 'page', this.currentPage);

const response = await axios.get('/products?' + usp)
```

This way, you will have it *actually* undefined on the back-end and you will not have to perform such silly workarounds.

If Mr. Undefined ever visits your page, he will be very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

You do string concatenation there, that's why `console.log(typeof searchQuery)` logs `string`. Certainly there are framework-specific options to deal with this on the backend, but the easiest solution would be to check for `searchQuery  === 'undefined'`.
Maybe it is possible to check `searchQuery` already on the frontend and not include it in the query?